# Evaluate the sum $1-\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}-\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Evaluate the sum $1-\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}-\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\ldots$

Been looking for a way to arrive at a solution. Would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: Hint: use $1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^3}+\cdots=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: Note that this is the alternating form of the [Basel Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem): $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}. $$ This implies that your series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: It's also helpful to recall that you can manipulate series (in the intuitive ways) if the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: $\frac 1 {2^2} + \frac 1 {4^2} + ... = \frac 1 {2^2} \left(   \frac 1 {1^2} + \frac 1 {2^2} + ...\right)$

Comment: Combine @xpaul's & J.W.Tanner's comments to get an answer...

Comment: $(1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^3}+\cdots)-2(\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{4^2}+\frac1{6^2}+\cdots)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-2(\frac1{2^2}\times\frac{\pi^2}{6})=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$